# Looking to simplify multiple variables in if statement

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I attempted to simplify this code:

```
for word in wordlist:
    if (word != 'a' and
        word != 'i' and
        word != 'and' and
        word != 'this' and
        word != 'is' and
        word != 'in'):
```

into

```
commom_words = ['a', 'i', 'and', 'this', 'is', 'in]

for word in wordlist:
   if word != any(common_words):
```

I also tried `all(common_words)`.

Using the original code, the common words were omitted from my search of the text. When I tried to simplify them in the variable, the common words were getting through if the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to use the `not in` syntax:

```
common_words = ['a', 'i', 'and', 'this', 'is', 'in']
for word in wordlist:
    if word not in common_words:
        # Do something with it...
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect :)